# Unable to declare Java Constants as static

Tags: java

I am getting error-"*Illegal modifier for parameter DEFAULT_CATALOG, only final is permitted*" in below (Bold part), Why I am not able to declare constant as static. Instead of directly using variable in my other class, I want to use contants. Kindly help.

```
package com.asc.scheduler.test;

import atg.adapter.gsa.query.Constant;

public class AscConstants {

    public static void schedulerContants(){

        **public static final String DEFAULT_CATALOG = "defaultCatalog";**

    }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

`DEFAULT_CATALOG` is a variable local to your method `schedulerContants()`.  As such, it thinks `DEFAULT_CATALOG` is supposed to be a local variable, yet you added `static` modifier to it, which doesn't make sense.  You probably meant to make that a member of `AscConstants`, so:

```
public class AscConstants {
    public static final String DEFAULT_CATALOG = "defaultCatalog";

    public static void schedulerConstants(){

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.But without a static method I am not able to use these constants in other class. package com.ascena.scheduler.test;

public final class AscConstants {

 public static final String DEFAULT_CATALOG = "defaultCatalog";
 public static final String ROOT_CATEGORY = "allRootCategories";
 public static final String CATEGORY_PROPERTY = "displayName";
 public static final String CATEGORY_TYPE = "childCategories";

}  e.g I am not able to use DEGAULT_CATALOG in other class. What should I do in order to use it?

Comment: @user3554403 Sure you can, unless I'm missing something.  You can access the value of `DEFAULT_CATALOG` by doing `AscConstants.DEFAULT_CATALOG`.